# fill cell completely when there are paddings

Tags: html, css

I want to fill background color for table cell. The cell have padding, therefore the cell not filled completely. This is [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/HKWa4/). For example, the second cell in the first row.

This is my styles:

```
.named-schedule-table td {
    border-width: 1px 0 0 1px;
    vertical-align: top ;
    text-align: center ;
    border-style: solid;
    line-height: 1.6em;
     overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0.4em 0.6em;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.appearance {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #CFDDEE;
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    cursor: pointer;
    margin: 3px 1px 3px 1px;
    height: 25px;
    line-height: 25px;
    text-align: center;
}

.current-day {
    background-color: #FCF8E3
}
```

Comment: second cell has two bg colors, what do you want exactly?

Comment: Please make your question clear. There are two backgrounds for the cell.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove padding from the cell and add it to `.appearence`.

Answer (score 0):

Remove this style from `.appearance` and add it to `named-schedule-table td background`:

```
.appearance: none repeat scroll 0 0 #CFDDEE;
```